# Time complexity of classical period finding

Tags: prime-numbers, computer-science, prime-factorization

Shor's algorithm for a quantum computer uses period finding in the quantum part to factor a number. For example, finding $r$ in $1 = a^r \; (mod \; N)$ will allow you to find two factors of a number $N$.

There also exists a step by step algorithm to calculate this period $r$ classically, which I found [here](https://intra.ece.ucr.edu/%7EKorotkov/courses/EE214-QC/QC-5-Shor.pdf).

1. Pick a random number $$ ($ < $).
   Check that coprime with $$.
2. Find smallest $r$, for which a $a^r ≡ 1 \; (mod \; N)$ (i.e., $r$ is the order of $a$).
3. If $r$ is odd, choose another $a$ and repeat (go back to Step 1).
   Probability of going back is ∼50%.
4. If $r$ is even, then $a^{\frac{r}{2} − 1} a^{\frac{r}{2} + 1} ≡ 0 \; (mod \; )$.
   If $a^{\frac{r}{2} + 1} ≡ 0\; (mod \; N)$, choose another  and repeat (go back
   to Step 1; this is very rare).
5. Since $N$ =  and  &  are primes, then $a^{\frac{r}{2} - 1}$ is a multiple of ,
   and $a^{\frac{r}{2} + 1}$ is a multiple of  (or vice versa).
   Find the greatest common divisor (GCD) of  and $a^{\frac{r}{2} ± 1}$,
   they will be  and .

Is there a time complexity for step 2 (classically)? Or specifically the period finding algorithm?

PS: I am not asking about prime factorization in general, just period finding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I don't think we know any period finding algorithms that are faster than linear in the period size. You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) for some algorithms that are in that area which are memory efficient.

But, if you have a sequence $a_l$ where you are able to compute $a_l$ for large $l$ efficiently, then you can use the [Baby-step giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) algorithm to find (a multiple of) the period of $a_l$. This is the case in your algorithm, since we can compute $a^l \bmod n$ in $\mathcal{O}(\log(l))$ operations mod $n$.
This leads to an $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ algorithm to complete step 2 (omitting factors $\log(n)$).

However, if you know on top of that, that the period is [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number), then you can do the following.
As an example, we can use your sequence that we find in step 2 again:
Note that $r \mid (p-1)(q-1)$. Assume that $p-1$ and $q-1$ are both $k$-smooth, where $k$ is not too big. Define
\begin{equation}
m = \prod_{r \text{ prime}}^{k} r^{\lfloor{\log_r{n}\rfloor }}.
\end{equation}
Then you can check that $a^m = 1 \bmod n$. By throwing away factors $r$ you can also obtain the exact period this way.
In practice we usually don't know beforehand if $(p-1)(q-1)$ is smooth or not. Therefore we try an $m$ as defined above and look if $a^m = 1 \bmod n$.
Since $m$ is of size $\mathcal{O}(n^k)$, this algorithm has complexity $\mathcal{O}(k\log(n))$ operations mod $n$. This is basically the idea behind [Pollard's $p − 1$ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm).
If $k$ is not too big, then this method is efficient, but in general it is not.